# Intel graphics card but only NVIDIA drivers installed

Tags: gpu-driver

Novice enquiry!
I have an intel HD graphics 620 card on my aspire f5 laptop but I can only find nvidia drivers installed - [list of drivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ni4KS.png) - maybe I'm missing something.
Neither can I find out how to install the necessary intel driver in any case!

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to install any drivers for Intel GPU's. They are natively supported by Linux kernel.